# Single self-service portal for Azure hybrid cloud

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, sccm, azure-pack

If we extend out datacenter with Azure cloud services to create a hybrid cloud infrastructure, is it possible to perform self-service provisioning and management of infrastructure (like VMs) from a single portal? Basically I would like to be able to provision a VM on demand either to the Azure cloud or my on-premises datacenter from a single portal.

I am aware of Windows Azure Pack, but if I understand correctly, it can only provision VMs on the private cloud, not on the Azure cloud. From what I read, this also holds true for System Center VMM SSP 2.0 (I may be wrong).

Can I use any of the above two for this purpose if I establish ExpressRoute connection between my datacenter and Azure? In case there is no out-of-the-box solution, can anybody point me towards a custom solution to build a single portal to deploy and remove VMs in such a hybrid cloud scenario?

Comment: You would have to use a cloud orchestration tool to provide a single portal across Azure and your on-premise data center. HP CSA is one such tool though I don't have experience using it. If you search on HP CSA and its' competitors you might get a good list of cloud orchestration products to begin with.    Alternatively, you could enhance your current self-service portal for on-premise data center to recognize Azure requests and then behind the scenes use the Azure pack to actually do the actions, this second option is quite extensive and would take a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out HP CSA. I found it does have a module providing a single tool for ordering in both private and public cloud environments. However, I also found System Center App Controller which can be used to manage virtual machines and services across private and public clouds: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546834.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this can be done using System Center 2012 SP1 - App Controller and Virtual Machine Manager.

App Controller provides a common self-service experience that can help you easily configure, deploy, and manage virtual machines and services across private and public clouds.

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546834.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is already a feedback for it. Might be under construction :)

Add all Azure services to Azure Pack
(https://feedback.azure.com/forums/255259-azure-pack/suggestions/6445143-add-all-azure-services-to-azure-pack)

> That’s what we strive towards: a consistent experience! What would you
>   say are the services you are most anxious to see come on-premises
>   first?

Comment: Sorry, the link is about bringing all Azure services on premises, not  about single portal to manage public and on-premises resources.